# Firefox - allow Select All in text field while allowing only numbers and period

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I've come up with the following code to restrict a currency input. A user can use home, end and arrow keys, but ctrl + a is blocked because FireFox isn't recognizing the key combination. This works correctly in Chrome and IE.

Is there a way to allow select all in a field in FireFox or is this a bug in FireFox? (or perhaps a bug in other browsers that I'm 'exploiting'?)

```
function autoFormatNumeric(field, e) {
  var charCode = e.which ? e.which : field.keyCode;
  if ((charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myInput").on('focus',function(){
  $(this).select(); // <- This jquery function select all even in firefox
});
```